# Where to set calcite elasticsearch username/password?

Tags: apache-calcite

I am trying to use Apache Calcite to connect to ElasticSearch, and am running into problems setting the Username Password.

I have tried to config username/password with `operand`(based on JSON), with Properties(`DriverManager.getConnection(String url, Properties config)`) and with `DriverManager.getConnection(String url, username, password)`, but have not been able to get any of them to work.

I have previously posted the question to [Apache JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-4180)

My Code is as follows

Trying to set username password with properties

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("lex", "JAVA");
String sql = "select * from index";

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:model=src/main/resources/es.json", config)) {
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
            printRs(rs);
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to set it with operand

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultSchema": "elasticsearch",
  "schemas": [
    {
      "type": "custom",
      "name": "elasticsearch",
      "factory": "org.apache.calcite.adapter.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSchemaFactory",
      "operand": {
        "coordinates": "{'192.168.133.104': 9200}",
        "jdbcUser": "elastic",
        "jdbcPassword": "elastic"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and throw Exception

```
{
    "error":{
        "root_cause":[
            {
                "type":"security_exception",
                "reason":"missing authentication token for REST request [/_alias]",
                "header":{
                    "WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8""
                }
            }
        ],
        "type":"security_exception",
        "reason":"missing authentication token for REST request [/_alias]",
        "header":{
            "WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8""
        }
    },
    "status":401
}
```

Comment: regarding the code from the jira I have made an edit and put it into the post, but it still needs to be okayed by a moderator - once it is okayed perhaps you can add in what exceptions if any you get when you try to run your code? As well as what gets printed from printRs(rs); if anything?

Comment: is the exception you get the one referenced in your throw exception - missing authentication token for REST request ?

Comment: yeah, the connection failed because the authentication failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not possible at the time this question has asked, but this functionality [has since been added](https://github.com/apache/calcite/commit/e9f926165c035ff62942dea318c5820ed69c1124) and will be included in the next release of Calcite (1.26.0). Alongside the `coordinates` key in the configuration, you can add `username` and `password` to specify authentication parameters.